# How to enable window chrome by using C# code and not XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window-chrome

So I am using the [WPFShell](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell) to apply chrome to a custom window. I have learned from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library) that in order to use it, I have to reference the [Microsoft.Windows.Shell library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=WPFShell&DownloadId=11220) and use this XAML code:

```
<shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <shell:WindowChrome
    ResizeBorderThickness="6"
    CaptionHeight="43"
    CornerRadius="25,25,10,10"
    GlassFrameThickness="0">
    </shell:WindowChrome>
</shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

**My question is, how do I enable chrome by using C# code and not XAML?** (i.e. How do I apply chrome in code-behind?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ah, stupid me. It was easy:

```
WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(this, new WindowChrome());
```

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is a older question, But I noticed that I couldn't get `WindowChrome.GetWindowChrome()` to work in .NET 4.5. I'm not sure if this has to do with `System.Windows.Shell` being included within the `PresentationFramework` assembly. But since it kept returning `null` there would be no way to update the chrome.

So my solution was to add a 'Name' to the `WindowChrome` which made it accessible in Code Behind.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="SomeProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
    mc:Ignorable="d"Title="Some Window" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="CanResize" 
    AllowsTransparency="True">

    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome x:Name="chrome" ResizeBorderThickness="6" CaptionHeight="0"
                      GlassFrameThickness="0" CornerRadius="0" UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

</window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Window;    

namespace SomeProject
{
    public partial class MainWindow: Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            //Get Existing 'WindowChrome' Properties.
            var captionHeight = chrome.CaptionHeight;

            //Set Existing 'WindowChrome' Properties.
            chrome.GlassFrameThickness = new Thickness(2d);

            //Assign a New 'WindowChrome'.
            chrome = new System.Windows.Shell.WindowChrome();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone who needs it.